# Retrieving values from a set

Tags: python, set, containers

I'm dealing with a problem involving a lot of objects (B). Heavy calculations are performed when these objects are initialized, depending on some of their properties. As this set (in the mathematical sense) of properties is often shared by these objects, I've wrapped the properties themselves in another object (C), resulting in a nice speed-up as the calculations are only performed once per different C.

My list of Bs is held in an object A, responsible for their initializations. Each B has a reference to a C and A holds a (pythonic) set of the different Cs (c_set). When I add a new B to A, I check if its C exists in c_set (the hash only depends on input parameters); if it does, I change this new B's C attribute to the version existing in the set, which has already been properly initialized. Something like:

```
class A:
    def add_b(self, b: B):
        if b.c in self.c_set:
            for c in self.c_set:
                if c is b.c:
                    break
            b.c = c
        else:
            self.initialize(c, other_params)  # the heavy bit
            self.c_set.add(c)
        self.b_list.add(b)
```

It works fine, but I'm not completely satisfied of the way I "salvage" existing values from the set. I wonder if there are alternative constructions for what I'm doing here, basically fishing a value from a set. My second idea  would be to use a dictionary whose values are identical to the keys; so I could just write `c = c_dict[c]` but it seems a bit overshot!

I don't know if other less common data structures could suit my use case.

Comment: In my opinion your idea using a dictionary is an efficient and simple (and therefore good) approach. I don't know anything in the standard library that would fit better here.

Comment: If the problem is repeating exactly the same heavy calculations see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html?highlight=lru_cache#module-functools) for the use of `cache` or `lru_cache`.